# Redirect Image Url to a page via htaccess

Tags: images, redirect, urls, htaccess

I am trying to redirect Image Urls to a page. I have used 301 [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin, but that doesn't seem to work.

For ex : [http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Contestant-11.jpg](http://#) should redirect to mywebsite.com/page

I have used 'Link to' to 'Media File' in individual image settings since I am using Social gallery plugin and it needs images to be linked to 'Media File' (since it is a Lightbox social sharing plugin)

How can I redirect all the image URls to a page of my choice using htaccess?

Comment: You'll need a `.htaccess` rewrite to intercept the request - your link settings in WordPress only affect *where* the image links to, not the actual URL of the file!

Comment: Does editing the .htaccess file in the wordpress installation do the job?

Comment: What do mean "in the WordPress installation"?

Comment: There is a .htaccess file in the directory Wordpress is installed.

Comment: Yep, that's the one.

Comment: What code should I insert into the .htaccess file to redirect the image to page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a rewrite rule to your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/wp-admin/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/.+?\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$ /my-page [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Add this after anything added by WordPress. You'll need to replace `/my-page` with the slug of the page you'd like to redirect to.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. But all the images on the website are broken and not being displayed.

Comment: Well yeah, because they redirect to the page.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there any way to redirect individual images to 'my-page' instead of the folder itself.

Comment: Yes, just use `Redirect /wp-content/uploads/file.jpg /page-to-redirect-to`

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was solved.

I have a pet contest website where users vote on pet photos. Users can also share  the Pet photos on social networks.

The problem until now was when a user shares a pet photo on Facebook, only the image was shared and not the page. So with your help, I managed to redirect the image to the pet contest page. But now, when the user shares a particular pet photo, the pet-contest page is being shared with the thumbnail of the first pet photo on the page.

Can you kindly suggest a workaround for this problem.